# Django. Empty_label custom value

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I want to change the value of default `empty_label` of field.
So I did something like this with my field in:

```
class RFXDigestModelForm(ModelForm):
    Time_frame_is_realistic = ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=models.RFXDigest.objects.all(),
        empty_label="(Nothing)",
        )

    class Meta:
        model = models.RFXDigest
        widgets = {
            'Time_frame_is_realistic': rfx_widgets.jQueryRadioSelect(),
        }
```

In result I have my own label for `empty_label`. But there is an issue:  my widget doesn't appear on the page, instead django comboBox appear.
How could i fix this?
And can I somehow pass choice list to `queryset` parameter of `ModelChoiceField`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the `widgets` dictionary if you're manually defining the field - put it in the field declaration.

```
Time_frame_is_realistic = ModelChoiceField(queryset=models.RFXDigest.objects.all(),
                                           empty_label="(Nothing)",
                                           widget=rfx_widgets.jQueryRadioSelect())
```

I don't understand your second question. If you want a custom choice list, use a normal ChoiceField rather than a ModelChoiceField.

Comment: Yeah, I should probably use ChoiceField. And in this case just need add one more value into choice list. But thank you for help. It works.